# Creating revision history for a file

Tags: sharepoint

I have 5 different files on my computer and now I want to upload them into Sharepoint creating 5 different revisions for the same entry in Sharepoint.

How do I do that?

So the titles are file v1.doc, file v2.doc, ... file v5.doc

They should become 5 different versions for the same file.

Lotus Notes Domino allows you to check in ANY file and make it a new version. But Sharepoint is anal about it and insists that all versions have the same filename. Is there anyway to fool it?

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to Do it programatically ?

if Yes then when you are uploading file to sharepoint server , you should first rename it with the name that you want to create vesioning.

After that when you upload your file it will be uploaded as a newer version , then a nerwer file.

Hope this helps.